# Connecting a print/file server with no wired access

Tags: wireless-networking

We currently have a printer server which also serves as a file server. The server is located on premise however is not close to any wired access point i.e. a patch panel or point. The server also requires access to the Internet as it transmits files across. We have a wireless modem and a wireless router. I can run a cable between the server and wireless router. How can I have the wireless router communicate with the wireless modem? If the operating system of the server is concerned, it is running Windows Server 2003.

**EDIT**

1. All devices are on the same subnet
2. The wireless router is a non-brand as is the wireless modem so am unsure whether the firmware can be upgraded on the wireless router
3. An article at http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-turn-an-old-router-into-a-wireless-bridge/ suggests using a client bridge however at a first glance the wireless router I have does not support this feature.

Comment: If the clients and wireless router are on the same subnet, it should work.  More info abut the network would help geta  better answer.

Comment: @Dave M - Sorry. Yes they are all on the same subnet. What other information do you require and be happy to provide it?

Comment: Can you see if the wireless router and modem supports WDS (wireless distribution service)?

Comment: @Paul - Will that appear as an option? If so, there is no such option.

Comment: I think you are out of luck then - you need to bridge the two as you suspect, and so the router either needs to do ap-to-ap, via wds, or stop being an AP and be a client, bridging the switchports.  You can do the latter with something like dd-wrt firmware, but as it is unbranded there is no way to know whether it is compatible.  edit: Oh, I just saw your link suggests dd-wrt also.

Comment: @Paul - Does WDS or Wireless Distribution System appear as an option i.e. do I have to select or check enable WDS? What do you mean by `bridging the switch ports`?

Comment: Yeah, WDS would be an obvious option.  By `bridging the switchports`, I mean that the lan ports would be bridged to the wifi ports, so that any packets arriving on the lan ports would be forwarded over wifi.  This is called `client bridge` mode in dd-wrt.  The alternative is that the wifi and switchports are on different networks, and you route from lan to wifi instead of bridge.

Comment: @Paul - Thanks. Don't quite follow bridging the switch ports so will drop you an email.